# Custom site logo only showing for site administrators

Tags: 2013, branding, sharepoint-on-prem, site-logo

I have a publishing site with custom master.
When I access the site as a administrator everthing works fine. However, when I access as a normal user (even as site owner), everything but the siteLogo is displayed.

The image URL is resolved correctly, but the site cannot load the resource. However, when I add the URL manually to the browser, the user can access the resource.

The image lies in the /_catalogs/masterpage/ folder, is checked in and published.

Any ideas on the issue?

Thank you for your help,
Markus

Comment: change the image location, put it on publishing images folder. This is permission issues, Not all user can read from /_catalogs/masterpage/